# c statement equivalent to mongo query db.users.find({age {$gt: 3}}, {})

Tags: c, mongodb

I have searched for the usage of conditional statements(`<`,`>`,`<=`,etc..,) in C API documentation in the link http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/. But I am unable to find it.

Example:

The mongo shell query is

```
db.users.find({age: {$gt: 3}}, {})
```

I want the equivalent C statement for the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, query:

```
find({ age : { $gt : 5, $lt : 12}})
```

would be written like this:

```
bson_init(&b);
bson_append_start_object(&b,"age");
bson_append_int(&b,"$gt",5);
bson_append_int(&b,"$lt",12);
bson_append_finish_object(&b);
bson_finish(&b);
```

Comment: mark the answer then, so that others don't have to waste their time

Comment: I'm new to this group, can u tell me where I have to mark the answer.

Comment: well, welcome to stackoverflow :) to mark an answer click on the check box outline to the left of the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Ok, you got the bson value to request, but how this request it's made? what's the method that must be called to retrieve this data?